# Smallest integer $k$ such that a non-elementary function is $o(x^k)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics

> Defining the function $h:(1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ by
>   $$h(x)=\int_1^x \ln(t^4 + 1)\mbox{ }dt,$$
>   I wish to find the smallest integer $k$ such that
>   $h(x) = o(x^k) \mbox{ as } x\to\infty.$

That is, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x_0$ such that $|h(x)| < \varepsilon |x^k|$ whenever $x>x_0$. Since $h$ is only defined for $x>1$, both sides will be positive, and so we can drop the absolute value signs.

My intuition tells me that the answer is $k=5$, because $\ln(t^4 + 1)=o(t^4)$ as $t\to\infty$. However, I'm not sure how to give a rigorous proof using the formal definition, nor that this is indeed the smallest such $k$.

Comment: You can get a much tighter bound on $\ln(t^4+1)$ than $o(t^4)$. Indeed $\ln(t^4+1) \approx \ln(t^4) = 4 \ln t$. We can get $o(t^{\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: My hunch is that it is not $o(x)$ but it is $o(x^2)$ since $\ln(t^4+1)$ is $o(t^{\varepsilon})$ and taking the integral adds one $t$.